# JQuery append() causes horizontal flow chat not to flow, but jumps

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, append, transition

I'm currently running a script that wants to horizontal align all chat messages coming from an IRC feed and scroll through it, when new messages are added to the queue.

My problem is that when the queue has a new message inside the append of the newLine will adjust the width of the chatbox and with that messes up the transition effect, which normally secures that the chat is readable and doesn't scroll to fast. While there are new lines added and deleted later on the width repaint does lead to jump effects, which I want to avoid.

[Too fast Chat preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FpUxA.jpg)

There are different problems causing it. One is that the Twitch Chat, where the feed comes from, tends to be very very active, which leads to many new messages and the 2nd problem is that the chat messages can be very long, so scrolling needs to be slow enough to show them.

So basically, how can I ensure that append() doesn't make my focus on the current message jump? How can I have a constant flowing transition effect, so new messages scroll in and aren't just added to the end.

Maybe the best solution is to just add the new messages to the chatbox in a non visible field on the right as long as the focus remains the same and is not changed through the new width. But I have no idea, how i could do that.

```js
 setInterval(function() {
        if (Chat.vars.queue.length > 0) {
            var newLines = Chat.vars.queue.join('');
            Chat.vars.queue = [];
            var old_width = $('#chat_box').width();
            $('#chat_box').append(newLines + " ");
            var offset = old_width - $('#chat_box').width();

            $('#chat_box').css('transition', 'right 0s');
            $('#chat_box').css('right', offset + 'px');

            setTimeout(function() {
              $('#chat_box').css('transition', 'right 1s');
              $('#chat_box').css('right', '3px');
            }, 20);

            $('#chat_box')[0].scrollTop = $('#chat_box')[0].scrollHeight;
            var linesToDelete = $('#chat_box .chat_line').length -  Chat.vars.max_messages;

            if (linesToDelete > 0) {
              for (var i = 0; i < linesToDelete; i++) {
                $('#chat_box').contents().eq(0).remove();
                // $('#chat_box .chat_line').eq(0).remove();
              }
            }

          }
          else if (getParameterByName('fade')) {
            var messagePosted = $('#chat_box .chat_line').eq(0).data('timestamp');
            if ((Date.now() - messagePosted) / 1000 >= Chat.vars.maxDisplayTime) {
              $('#chat_box .chat_line').eq(0).addClass('on_out').fadeOut(function() {
                $(this).remove();
              });
            }
          }
        }, 250);
```

```css
#chat_box {
      background-color: transparent;
      font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 20px;
      font-style: normal;
      font-variant: normal;
      font-weight: normal;
      position: absolute;
      overflow: hidden;
      color: #D3D3D3;
      border-radius: 4px;
    
      text-align: right;
      white-space: nowrap;
      height: 48px;
      line-height: 48px;
      right: 200;
      padding-right: 5px;
      text-shadow:
      2px 2px 1px #000,
      -1px 2px 1px #000,
      2px -1px 1px #000,
      -1px -1px 1px #000;
}
```

Comment: welcome, new user. here are some tips for improving the quality of your question: (1) include your HTML, and tell us what you tried before asking your question. (2) try to reduce the problem down to only the necessary parts. remove pieces that are not relevant to narrow down what's causing the problem. This will take lots of trial and error, but you'll learn a lot. (3) brush up on your fundamentals. Browse through the HTML, CSS, and JavaScript pages on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web) first, and then read the [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/) docs.